# cannot upload or get any file using AWS S3 using react native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I used AWS S3 as file storage and i cannot upload or get any files from  bucket. here is my code and can someone please help me to fix this issue. i am getting `AWSS3Provider - error uploading AccessDenied: Access Denied`

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, Text, TouchableOpacity, View,} from 'react-native';
import Amplify, {Storage} from 'aws-amplify';
import {awsmobile} from "./aws-exports";

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    async callerFn() {
        try {
            let file = 'My upload text';
            let name = 'myFile.txt';
            const access = {level: "public"}; // note the access path
            await Storage.put(name, file, access);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.callerFn()}>
                        <Text>Press to Upload</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I have granted all permissions for user i have used.
and here is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Id": "PolicyXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "StmtXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Action": [
          "s3:*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::experimental/*",
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/amplify-XXXXX"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I never tried `aws-amplify` by myself.

**Solutions**

But I do use AWS S3 on my app to both uploads & download my files. Make sure you set correct **IAM policy** according to the readme.

Here is how I do it using [react-native-aws3](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3#readme)

```
import { RNS3 } from 'react-native-aws3';

const file = {
  // `uri` can also be a file system path (i.e. file://)
  uri: "assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=655DBE66-8008-459C-9358-914E1FB532DD&ext=PNG",
  name: "image.png",
  type: "image/png"
}

const options = {
  keyPrefix: "uploads/",
  bucket: "your-bucket",
  region: "us-east-1",
  accessKey: "your-access-key",
  secretKey: "your-secret-key",
  successActionStatus: 201
}

RNS3.put(file, options).then(response => {
  if (response.status !== 201)
    throw new Error("Failed to upload image to S3");
  console.log(response.body);
  /**
   * {
   *   postResponse: {
   *     bucket: "your-bucket",
   *     etag : "9f620878e06d28774406017480a59fd4",
   *     key: "uploads/image.png",
   *     location: "https://your-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads%2Fimage.png"
   *   }
   * }
   */
});
```

Comment: yes this is what i am using currently. but with latest react native version this is taking time more than before. and sometimes upload getting failed.